# Serializing vertex_descriptor of a boost::graph separately?

Tags: serialization, boost, graph, stl, dictionary

Is there any way to make `vertex_descriptor` of a `boost::graph` serializable? Boost does define `<boost/graph/adj_list_serialize.hpp>` for serializing the whole graph structure, but not separately.

I have an adjacency-list graph which contains 3dvector (which represents 3d world in X, Y, Z coordinates by the way) vertices as such

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
        boost::listS,
        boost::listS,
        boost::undirectedS,
        3dvector>
    Graph;

typedef Graph::vertex_descriptor VertexId;
typedef Graph::edge_descriptor EdgeId;
```

However I also need to keep a separate mapping information for lookup and this is where the problem is: boost doesn't know how to serialize `VertexId`. They are stored in an STL map as such: `std::map<string, VertexId>` so that a string lookup can return the right vertex in the graph, as a `vertex_descriptor` is essentially a reference that points to a specific vertex in the graph.

My intention is to serialize both the graph and the map into a file, but I can't find a way to serialize the `vertex_descriptor`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the graph and the locations (some vector/list of vertices). You will have to write the serialization method for whatever represents your vertices.

```
template<typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive &ar, LatLon &loc, const unsigned int /*version*/) {
    ar &loc.latitude &loc.longitude;
}
```

Now you can serialize your graph using:

```
std::vector<LatLon> locations; // or a list
archive & graph & locations;
```

Where `graph` is the adjencency_list and `locations` is a vector/list of LatLon classes/structs. I think boost already knows how to handle the list/vector.

Comment: I have no problems storing my own data, storing STL is also no problem. The problem is how to serialize the boost::graph_traits::vertex_descriptor (which is the value in the key/value pair in the map). It's not clear how I'm supposed to do it, it doesn't seem to expose any internal member so I got the feeling that it is meant to be used as an opaque datatype

Comment: What do you use as vertex_descriptor? Isn't it already serialized together with the graph?

Comment: I use `boost::listS` as my vertex type. Is this what you asked? Yes, it is stored in the graph but I also keep a separate `map<string, vertex_descriptor>` that I also want to serialize. And this is where the problem is: boost knows how to serialize `std::map`, `std::string`, but not `boost::vertex_descriptor` HINT: I typedef-ed `vertex_descriptor` as `VertexId` above in case anyone didn't notice

Comment: When you use a list the vertext_descriptor is a list iterator. Maybe try using VecS instead (this is usually also faster), then it's an integer.

Comment: It is possible but that would require lots of changes to my algorithm as I'm not prepared to deal with having to repair lots of iterator as I do lots of adding/removing from the graph. It's a pity that we can't serialize iterators (which might be due to the complexity involved in making it happen). I decided to just rebuild the mapping whenever necessary as its a more realistic option for me.